# PHP: Need the lightest/most-efficient way to generate a signature from a string

Tags: php, encoding, signature

QUICK SUMMARY/Straight to the point:

What's the lightest and fastest way to convert a large block of html code/text/data into a short signature string?

I tried 
  $data_signature =  md5($htmlOutput);

where $htmlOutput is a HTML formatted table w/ 100 rows of name, age, address data.. and this resulted in a nice short string:
  $data_signature = 'e33fbcb944648eca3d5ce9ed69bfd3cc1391648400';

W/c is basically what I need, but since my app will be running this every second (data refresh) I am interested to know if there's a better way of doing this, that has minimal processing impact on the server (if ever md5 is processor hungry - i dont know) .. or is this "OK" already?

Worth noting: I do not need safety/encryption, i just need a way to create a signature of the output for comparative purposes.

DETAILS (just for those wondering)

I have a web app (JQUERY) loading JSON data from a PHP.

JSON Data coming are 2 Objects:
 status="ok"
 output= the HTML formatted output (rows of divs etc)

The web app basically reloads data from PHP every second... and then writes that HTML output into a DIV on the page = typical.

But to make the app more efficient, I wanted it to reload only if it needs to.

I wanted to add a 3rd object in the mix that basically tells the app if there's any reason for UPDATE (like a new row)

At the moment i have this 3rd object:

$latest_signature = unix timestamp from the latest row in the database table

This value is passed back and forth 
jquery sends this to PHP on every load, PHP then evaluates this and loads/outputs only if there's a new row in the DB, and passes the new latest_signature value w/ the updated epoch time it generates output.

So basically instead of reloading the same data, the whole thing will refresh / reload /rerender only when there's actually a new row.

This works and is very processor-efficient except that this doesn't account for UPDATES done to any existing rows! lol .. So when a row in the database is updated, the display will not refresh, until a NEW row is inserted.

SO, i thought of doing something like creating a signature for the whole block of html output.. like convert that to some sort of encoding that represents the whole block of output..

thanks guys!

Comment: Considered a hook in code to update this global timestamp you track, or accomplish the same in code using a database trigger?  A trigger that updates this value whenever the table received an update, alternately just index the column and track at the row level selecting the the last modified.

Comment: those actually pretty valid suggestions man thanks. I did look into something like that, like a trigger table or something, even just a txt file.. but i really wanted minimal dependencies, i wanted my app to figure things out on its own w/ relying on other logic. simply = IF DATA is SAME dont do anything. saves bytes, and processing power